# Varian File Uplaoder in loop not working

Tags: magento-1.7, module, image

I am trying to upload multiple files in a loop using **Varien_File_Uploader**

```
for($i=0;$i<count;$i++){
 $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
        array(
    'name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['name'][$key],
    'type' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['type'][$key],
    'tmp_name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['tmp_name'][$key],
    'error' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['error'][$key],
    'size' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['size'][$key]
        )
  );
}
```

My first file uplaoding successfully but in loop for second one i am getting error as "**File was not uploaded**"

I find out that this error comes when **tmp_name** is not set.

I checked out it's correct. For the first entry **tmp_name is set** but not for second entry.

I am not getting why tmp_name is setting only for the first one & not for others.
Anyone can please help.

Comment: Can you please post your full code ? @Akhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue.
The issue was with     **$key**. It should be unique in a loop. Because of this i was getting **tmp_name** null.

So i updated my below code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count;$i++){
 $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
    array(
'name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['name'][$key],
'type' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['type'][$key],
'tmp_name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['tmp_name'][$key],
'error' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['error'][$key],
'size' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['size'][$key]
    )
  );
}
```

to:

```
for($i=0;$i<count;$i++){
 $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
    array(
'name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['name'][$i],
'type' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['type'][$i],
'tmp_name' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['tmp_name'][$i],
'error' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['error'][$i],
'size' => $_FILES['my_image_'.$i]['size'][$i]
    )
  );
}
```

Now its working great. Thanks.